# How to detect a USB keyboard and how to change keyboard layout via CLI in Wayland?

Tags: keyboard-layout, 17.10, wayland

My good old Ubuntu used to detect my USB keyboard (having a different layout) with the command `xinput -list`, get device id, and then issue the command `setxkbmap -device "${ID}" -layout "${usbkbd_layout}"` to use it.

Under Ubuntu 17.10 (Wayland), things have got complicated. The command `setxkbmap` works only for some apps, like Chromium, and not for GNOME core apps, like gedit, terminal, nautilus, etc.

What is the Wayland equivalent of `setxkbmap` to change keyboard layout from command line?

Comment: https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/keyboard-layouts.html

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson : Thanks. The old GUI way described in the Help documentation has also some problems, like shortcut key combinations still requiring the default keyboard layout. I'm expecting a terminal command to implement the desired layout change really system-wide, if there is something like that. I'm afraid things are getting more and more like Windows here, offering fewer and fewer choices to users, and probably that's why Linux Mint is becoming more popular...

Comment: If you want you can logout and login again choosing "login with Xorg". then you have Xorg instead of wayland.