# alt tab not working on Ubuntu Mate 20.04.1 with external keyboard

Tags: drivers, keyboard, mate

I just switched back to Ubuntu mate after about 2 years. Unfortunately <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>tab</kbd> is not working for my left alt (with the right alt is fine) when I'm using my external keyboard (Razer Ornata Chroma). Also, the alt+` is working just fine with both alts.
Tried to rebind, unsuccessfully, tried to update keyboard driver/firmware but i'm not sure I did it correctly.
I'm assuming its keyboard problem but still...any ideas how to fix it ?

Update:

with my "internal" (laptop) keyboard:

KeyPress event, ... root 0x50a, subw 0x0, time 9051384, (593,207), root:(595,316), state 0x10, keycode 64 (keysym 0xffe9, Alt_L), same_screen YES,
FocusOut event, ... mode NotifyGrab, detail NotifyAncestor

FocusOut event, ... mode NotifyWhileGrabbed, detail NotifyNonlinear

PropertyNotify event, ... atom 0x15b (_NET_WM_STATE), time 9051568, state PropertyNewValue

with my external i have only "key press/ key release" events. Its like pressing alt is blocking the tab button

Update - Fixed:

After the initial install of OpenRazer and configuring Polychromatic, I have removed the OpenRazer and that fixed the problem.

Comment: what is the output of `xev` when you press that key combination? How does it differ from your "internal" keyboard?

Comment: with my "internal" (laptop) keyboard: 
KeyPress event, ...
    root 0x50a, subw 0x0, time 9051384, (593,207), root:(595,316),
    state 0x10, keycode 64 (keysym 0xffe9, Alt_L), same_screen YES,

FocusOut event, ...
    mode NotifyGrab, detail NotifyAncestor

FocusOut event, ...
    mode NotifyWhileGrabbed, detail NotifyNonlinear

PropertyNotify event, ...
    atom 0x15b (_NET_WM_STATE), time 9051568, state PropertyNewValue

with my external i have only "key press/ key release" events. Its like pressing alt is blocking the tab button

Comment: I've pasted the relavant data into your question. Please use the **edit** link below your question next time when you want to add more infos - don't use comments for that.

Comment: It's hard to parse the information in your question and the information you've added into comments because there is no formatting.  Without formatting we can't tell apart commands from the surrounding text.  Terminal output is stripped of line breaks and indentations.  Instead, please use the formatting tools at the top of the text box when you edit your question.  Alternatively, you can use Markdown language.  Please make sure that terminal output and commands are rendered in `monospace` font.

Answer (score 0):

If your external keyboard does not provide any keycodes, it seems that it is not recognized by the XServer. If you are using wayland, it might be helpful to switch to Xserver or look [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/971284/how-to-detect-a-usb-keyboard-and-how-to-change-keyboard-layout-via-cli-in-waylan) how to configure it in wayland.

What you should achieve in the first place is that xev should spill out a keycode on pressing that key combination.

If you are not sure if you installed the keyboard driver correctly, describe how you did it by editing your question. (not in a comment)